# Gini above 1 when bootstrapping

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, roc, gini

Let's say I have a dataset (data), which contains the binary target variable class and the predictions (probabilities in [0,1]).

```
 data<-data.frame(class=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1),predict=c(0.8,0.8,0.8,0.1,0.1,0.95,0.1,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.1,0.99))
    metric <- function (D, d) {return (Hmisc::somers2(D$predict[d], D$class[d])[2])}
    #metric(data)
    boot.data <- boot::boot(data,metric, R=1000, sim="ordinary", stype="i")
    ci <- boot::boot.ci(boot.data, conf=0.95, type="basic")
    ci
```

The results are:

```
Intervals : 
Level      Basic         
95%   ( 0.0286,  1.2878 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

I would like to ask why I get values above 1 (1.2878) for the error bar of the Gini, although Gini maximum value should be 1. I assume that there may be some kind of theoritical distribution fitted, through which the confidence interval is produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the type="basic" option used. I have no link to the original reference (Davison, A.C. and Hinkley, D.V. (1997) Bootstrap Methods and Their Application, Chapter 5. Cambridge University Press), but [[as described here]](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/notes/bootci-Notes.pdf) the basic method relies on standard errors and therefore will not respect the boundaries of your distribution. The 'BCa' (or last resort 'percent') method should give you the desired results.